# Wine-5.13: 0050:fixme:explorer:webbrowser_QueryInterface (...) interface not supported

Tags: 32-bit, wine, x86, discord

When running Discord with Wine, the following errors occur:

```
00e0:fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken QueryInformationToken( ..., TokenElevationType, ...) semi-stub
00e0:fixme:ieframe:DllGetClassObject {9ba05972-f6a8-11cf-a442-00a0c90a8f39} {00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} 0031DC5C
00e0:err:ole:apartment_getclassobject DllGetClassObject returned error 0x80040111 for dll L"C:\\windows\\system32\\ieframe.dll"
0050:fixme:explorer:webbrowser_QueryInterface (41C41D0C)->({00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} 0031E79C) interface not supported
0050:fixme:explorer:webbrowser_QueryInterface (41C41D0C)->({00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} 0031E714) interface not supported
0050:fixme:explorer:webbrowser_QueryInterface (41C41D0C)->({00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} 00819A38) interface not supported
00e0:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0031FE34 00000000): stub
```

Discord setup file I am using: https://dl.discordapp.net/distro/app/stable/win/x86/1.0.9002/DiscordSetup.exe

I am using [box86](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86/), but [this issue](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86/issues/393) implies that it is not an error with box86. I have seen this error on other systems too.
System info: Raspberry Pi 4B, RPi OS 32-bit, wine 32-bit, 4G RAM, 64G storage, 1.80GHZ 4-core CPU

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what is happening.

In windows, there is a thing called COM.  It is a way to link programs together that know nothing about each other.

Wine half assed their COM implementation of *ieframe.dll* and it doesn't have the juju that your program is attempting to access.  Not Wine's fault, ie sucks and everyone knows it.  The awesome folks making Wine might have spent more time on this but they didn't have any way to know what stupid interfaces a game was going to try to use.

You can possibly legally get this DLL elsewhere (but as SU does not allow me to help you steal or break the law so finding it legally is up to you).  And it *might* work.

If it *does* work.. please post back.

Also.. IMHO.. I run a Windows vm on my Linux box to play games.  Wine has a single threaded synchronization model and often not optimal for running games.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! First of all, Discord is not a game and thus does not require more than one thread to run decently. Second, I have considered using a Windows VM but I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B, which does not realisticly have enough power to run a full VM. I hope Discord will one day release a native Linux ARM version. And couldn't I use my other Linux PC to install Windows 32-bit in a VM and get the DLL that way?

Comment: You probably can get the DLL that way.  And yes.. I wasn't thinking when I wrote this post.  Discord is probably also multi threaded but that probably wont matter.  Wine is not an emulator ;) so.. no, it won't let x86/intel/amd code run on a raspi (as you assumed).  Even if you *could* run a VM, it would probably suck on that platform.  My RasPi is for running RetroPie :) Not windows.

Comment: FYI I am using box86 (https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86/) to run x86 binary. Wine does work and runs a lot of things with the help of box86 on a Raspberry Pi. When box64 is released I hope to run Discord with it better. For now I have to attempt running it with Wine. Any ideas where ieframe.dll would be on Windows?

Comment: `C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll` .. and don't expect 64 bit to be better.  It isn't.. in fact, it is slower.  Just because 64 is bigger than 32 doesn't make it faster.  The 64bit instruction set has a few advantages.. but that sure isn't going to help you when emulating them (as you would be doing).  This is also true on both linux and windows proper.  32 vs 64 bit differences are complicated.. most of the time, the 32bit one will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the path. And I am not expecting 64bit to be "better", instead it will increase the amount of programs you can run on ARM. And box86 and box64 are not emulators, rather, they use libaries on the local ARM machine to run a lot faster. WorldOfGoo runs perfectly well on my RPi with box86, and so does Wine (which has to run on top of box86 on ARM platforms) running things like Lego Digital Designer. Yes, most of the time, 32bit will be faster, but 64bit will be able to run a lot more programs that have been compiled for 64 bit only, for instance, Google Chome, Discord, and more.